# Intel VML add is slow

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl, intel-fortran

I wrote this small subroutine that compares simple vector mathematical functions, performed either with a loop:

```
f(i) = a(i) + b(i)
```

or direct:

```
f = a + b
```

or using Intel MKL VML:

vdAdd(n,a,b,f)

The timing results for n=50000000 are:

VML    0.9 sec
direct 0.4
loop   0.4

And I dont understand, why VML takes twice as long as the other methods!
(Loop is sometimes faster than direct)

Subroutine can be found under http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/L6dVLdAOIf
and called via

```
program test

  use vmltests
  implicit none

  call vmlTest()

end program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code have potential L2 cache issue, one can overcome it with blocking optimization. See Intel® Software Networks Forum answer for details: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=80041

Intel® Optimization Notice:

> Intel® compilers, associated libraries
>   and associated development tools may
>   include or utilize options that
>   optimize for instruction sets that are
>   available in both Intel® and non-Intel
>   microprocessors (for example SIMD
>   instruction sets), but do not optimize
>   equally for non-Intel microprocessors.
>   In addition, certain compiler options
>   for Intel compilers, including some
>   that are not specific to Intel
>   micro-architecture, are reserved for
>   Intel microprocessors.  For a detailed
>   description of Intel compiler options,
>   including the instruction sets and
>   specific microprocessors they
>   implicate, please refer to the “Intel®
>   Compiler User and Reference Guides”
>   under “Compiler Options."  Many
>   library routines that are part of
>   Intel® compiler products are more
>   highly optimized for Intel
>   microprocessors than for other
>   microprocessors.  While the compilers
>   and libraries in Intel® compiler
>   products offer optimizations for both
>   Intel and Intel-compatible
>   microprocessors, depending on the
>   options you select, your code and
>   other factors, you likely will get
>   extra performance on Intel
>   microprocessors.
>
> Intel® compilers, associated libraries
>   and associated development tools may
>   or may not optimize to the same degree
>   for non-Intel microprocessors for
>   optimizations that are not unique to
>   Intel microprocessors.  These
>   optimizations include Intel® Streaming
>   SIMD Extensions 2 (Intel® SSE2),
>   Intel® Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
>   (Intel® SSE3), and Supplemental
>   Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (Intel®
>   SSSE3) instruction sets and other
>   optimizations.  Intel does not
>   guarantee the availability,
>   functionality, or effectiveness of any
>   optimization on microprocessors not
>   manufactured by Intel. 
>   Microprocessor-dependent optimizations
>   in this product are intended for use
>   with Intel microprocessors.
>
> While Intel believes our compilers and
>   libraries are excellent choices to
>   assist in obtaining the best
>   performance on Intel® and non-Intel
>   microprocessors, Intel recommends that
>   you evaluate other compilers and
>   libraries to determine which best meet
>   your requirements.  We hope to win
>   your business by striving to offer the
>   best performance of any compiler or
>   library; please let us know if you
>   find we do not